# List show/add/remove View

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Looking for some best practices of UI list on iPhone which has item add/modify/delete functions. Please refer to some sample codes or articles to build user friendly interface.

The main application is tab bar application and one of the tabs supposed to show item management. The item itself consisting of 3 text items, first one can be label, it's short, the rest if it's not terribly complicated I would like to show below with small font or show when user taps on item entering edit mode... Not sure how to design all this and which views to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use UITableView to show the list. Standard tableview editing is pretty neat. You can find UI best practices [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html) and code samples [here](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code).